# Combobox - Change - Fire after 3 oder 4 values

Tags: vba, excel, combobox

I got a macro which opens a userform. Userform contains a combox.
Combox contains value from a loop which loops through all names of all worksheets in the workbook.
Sheet names are very similar, ab100, ab101, ab102,... etc.

When typing the number e.g.102 into the combobox value field , automatically like google smartsearch  value ab102 will be found and worksheet can be opend with button OK.

Code works very well wir 3digit nums, now Ive got 4digits nums and it doesnt work for it.

Any idea how to adjust it?

Many thanks in advance

Sebastian

```
Private Sub combSheets_Change()
Dim i As Integer


If Len(combSheets.Value) >= 3 Then

k = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets.Count
    ReDim strWorksheetsArray(1 To k)
    For i = 1 To k
    strWorksheetsArray(i) = Sheets(i).Name
    Next i

If disableChange = True Then
  disableChange = False
  Exit Sub
Else

  For i = 1 To k
    selSt = InStr(1, strWorksheetsArray(i), combSheets.Value)

'InStr searches a string for a substring, returns the substring position if found, or 0 if not found.  Use value to determine which text to select (highlight) in the combobox.

    If selSt <> 0 Then
        With combSheets
            .Value = strWorksheetsArray(i)
            .SelStart = selSt
            .SelLength = Len(combSheets.Value) - selSt
        End With
    Exit Sub
    End If
  Next i
End If
Else
End If

End Sub
```

Comment: How does it not work? What's the error or wrong pattern? I couldn't see any reason why it would work with 3 digits but not 4.

Comment: Either you are using a great many global variables or you are not using `Option Explicit`. Both would be poor design. Why not declare all of your variables as a matter of standard practice?

Comment: A guess: your code is first triggered when the length equals 3. This triggers some other event handler which in turn switches `disableChange` to `True`. When you get to 4 characters, you now hit the branch of the code for `disableChange = True`, which leads to `Exit Sub` before anything else happens.

Comment: Thanks guys for your remarks. Variable declaration indeed is not completed yet. John, I think you're right. I guess what I need is something like if I insert 3 digit it should be looking for all names with 3 digit inside and autocomplete it and if I quickly input 4 digits it should do the same for all 4digit including names. Any idea how to arrange it. If I put the first trigger to 4 its working for 4digit including named but not anymore for 3 digit ones. To remember: 3digitnames: ab100-el. 4digitnamed: ab1000-el